# How to find good documentation for Python modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I can't seem to find a good explanation of how to use Python modules. Take for example the `urllib` module. It has commands such as
`req = urllib.request.Request()`.

How would I find out what specific commands, like this one, are in certain Python modules?

For all the examples I've seen of people using specific Python modules, they just know what to type, and how to use them.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: "import urllib" is not the name of the module `import` is the statement that you use in your code so that you can use the module. As for the "commands" for the module you can look at the documentation for the module. Just google the module name and it's documentation.

Comment: `help(module-name)`.  How can you tell what to type for any feature in any language?  Read The Fine Manual https://docs.python.org/3/library/  There are plenty of sources on the web, you can also try https://pymotw.com/3/

Comment: I know, but the actual urllib module I am asking is how do you use the code within that module like the request.Request I know the reason for import.

Comment: Is the official documentation not sufficient? https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request We may not be understanding your question.

Comment: @Karin I believe he i asking in general, how one would go about using **any** python module. Such as learning it, or downloading and installing it(if need be).

Comment: You may be looking for [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir). Otherwise, it's not clear what your question is.

Comment: I just want to know for example the sys you can write say sys.stderr.write() and the sys module has loads of other commands, but how do I find what each module commands are like the sys with sys.stderr.write() or sys.stderr.flush() I hope that you all can understand that, sorry as I am new to python, but I can't find where to locate all the commands and what to type for the modules ifthat all makes sense.

Comment: I believe your looking for the python docs: https://docs.python.org/2/contents.html

Answer (score 1):

My flow chart looks something like this:

- Reading the published documentation (or use `help(moduleName)` which gives you the same information without an internet connection in a harder to read format). This can be overly verbose if you're only looking for one tidbit of information, in which case I move on to...
- Finding tutorials or similar stack overflow posts using specific keywords in your favorite search engine. This is generally the approach you will use 99% of the time.
- Just recursively poking around with `dir()` and `__doc__` if you think the answer for what you're looking for is going to be relatively obvious (usually if the module has relatively simple functions such as `math` that are obvious by the name)
- Looking at the source of the module if you *really* want to see how things works.